# Paypal Native Checkout Button keeps loading and then disappears on Android

Tags: java, android, paypal

I'm using the new Native Checkout SDK for Android with Java and I've been following every step in the documentation but this keeps happening and I don't know why

This is on
*my public class app extends Application*

```
        CheckoutConfig checkoutConfig = new CheckoutConfig(
            this,
            ID,
            Environment.SANDBOX,
            String.format("%s://paypalpay", BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID),
            CurrencyCode.MXN,
            UserAction.PAY_NOW,
            new SettingsConfig(
                    true,
                    false
            )
    );
```

On my fragment where the button is implemented

```
payPalButton.setup(
            createOrderActions -> {
                ArrayList purchaseUnits = new ArrayList<>();
                purchaseUnits.add(
                        new PurchaseUnit.Builder()
                                .amount(
                                        new Amount.Builder()
                                                .currencyCode(CurrencyCode.MXN)
                                                .value(amount)
                                                .build()
                                )
                                .build()
                );
                Order order = new Order(
                        OrderIntent.CAPTURE,
                        new AppContext.Builder()
                                .userAction(UserAction.PAY_NOW)
                                .build(),
                        purchaseUnits
                );
                createOrderActions.create(order, (CreateOrderActions.OnOrderCreated) null);
            },
            approval -> approval.getOrderActions().capture(result -> {
                Log.i("CaptureOrder", String.format("CaptureOrderResult: %s", result));
                 }),
            () -> {
                Log.d("OnCancel", "Buyer cancelled the PayPal experience.");
                Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(requireView(), R.string.la_donacion_no_fue_realizada, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                snackbar.getView().setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(),android.R.color.holo_red_light));
                snackbar.show();
            },
            errorInfo -> {
                Log.d("OnError", String.format("Error: %s", errorInfo));
                Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(requireView(), R.string.la_donacion_no_fue_realizada, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                snackbar.getView().setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(),android.R.color.holo_red_light));
                snackbar.show();
            }

    );
```

[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Solved It by adding this line in the extends application file:

```
 PayPalCheckout.setConfig(checkoutConfig);
```